# How to change how frequently SLURM updates the output file (stdout)?

Tags: stdout, slurm

I am using SLURM to dispatch jobs on a supercomputer. I have set the `--output=log.out` option to place the content from a job's stdout into a file (`log.out`). I'm finding that the file is updated every 30-60 minutes, making it difficult for me to check on the status of my jobs.

Any idea why it takes so long to update this file? Is there a way to change settings so that this file is updated more frequently?

Using SLURM 14.03.4-2

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This may be related to buffering.

Have you tried disabling output buffering as suggested in [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe)? I would recommend the stdbuf option:

```
stdbuf -o0 -e0 command
```

But can't be sure without more information, as I've never experienced a behavior like that. Which filesystem are you using?

Also if you are using srun to run your commands you can use the `--unbuffered` option which disables the output buffering.

Comment: You were right, it was totally related to buffering. My program was never flushing the stdout buffer. This is something I didn't realize I had to do until I started outputting stdout to a file.

Comment: Just to be clear, what is the `command` here -- the executable binary. Also where should I add this code in the script before `srun` or after it?

Comment: @NealKruis I had the same issue. In my case, I was using Python and `print` to print messages to the `.out` files. By changing the `print` command to `print(..., flush=True)`, the `.out` files were consistently updated while the code was being executed.

Comment: @rambalachandran suppose the script is called `code.py` the commend should be `srun --unbuffered python code.py`.